# Hide Sign Out Link in Liferay 6.2 Dockbar

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

In Liferay 6.1, we created a hook to hide the sign out link in the dockbar. However, when I look at the code for 6.2, I see the following:

```
<c:if test="<%= themeDisplay.isShowSignOutIcon() %>">
    <aui:nav-item cssClass="sign-out" href="<%= themeDisplay.getURLSignOut() %>" iconCssClass="icon-off" label="sign-out" />
</c:if>
```

No matter how much I google, I can't find any reference to themeDisplay.isShowSignOutIcon(), aside from the API reference, which does me no good, as it is not commented at all. I did find the page that discusses the native LR theme properties and apparently determining whether to show/hide a sign out linkn is not one of the native theme properties.

Does anyone know if you can set the theme itself to show/hide the sign out link and how you would go about doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too analyzed ServicePreAction code, and found that all this code does is:

- checks if the user is logged in or not
- if yes, shows 'sign out' link, not otherwise

You can simply create a hook to override `html/portlet/dockbar/view_user_account.jspf` to either remove that code snippet from this jsp to hide it for all scenarios OR modify the condition to show/hide as per your requirements.

Comment: Thanks Rushikesh. I guess I'll just create another hook to hide the link.

Answer (score 0):

The only place that I've found where `ThemeDisplay.setShowSignOutIcon` is called is in [ServicePreAction](https://github.com/olafk/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/events/ServicePreAction.java#L863) (linking master branch here). That being said, it looks like it's not configurable, but you can easily create another ServicePreAction in a hook. Please see an example in this plugin (referencing [portal.properties](https://github.com/olafk/liferay-custom-navigation/blob/master/docroot/WEB-INF/src/portal.properties) and [liferay-hook.xml](https://github.com/olafk/liferay-custom-navigation/blob/master/docroot/WEB-INF/liferay-hook.xml), but naturally there's also code that I'm sure you'll find. It's not big)

Another option - if you just want to unconditionally get rid of the link: Use CSS to hide it. Yes, it will still be there, but any way you choose to hide the link, the actopm at /c/portal/logout will still be available...

Comment: Thanks Olaf. Good thought about creating a plug-in to handle other functionality if we needed it. I thought of the CSS route, but then, if a user uses a different theme, the logout link would still be available (for example, using the control panel or classic theme in the control panel).